# SAM Deployment Fails with Size Issue For Lambda Function

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-cloudformation, aws-sam

After running

`sam build --use-container && sam deploy --guided`

CloudFormation fails with the following at the creation of the AWS Lambda Function

[CloudFormation Create Lambda Function Failed for Size Too Large](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Neqfo.png)

The 115885562 byte size translates to about 115 MB, and the Lambda limit is 250 MB when unzipped and including both function code and Layers.

Why might this fail?

EDIT: It seems that the 115885562 byte size refers to only the Lambda function and HAS taken into account the total of 250 MB (suggesting the referenced Lambda Layers were the remaining byte size--that was my main curiosity, which I've now deducted).

Comment: Why your function is so large?

Answer (score 0):

If you have any large dependencies your function rely on rather add Lambda layers for those dependencies than having them in your code. You will want your function to be as small as possible in any case, so removing the dependencies from your code and adding them into a Lambda layer will be better in the long run.

Comment: When you say remove dependencies from the code, what do you mean by that? Should I not have anything in the requirements.txt? Because in my template.yaml, I DO have the following section for Lambda Layers

`code`
Resources:
  HelloWorldFunction:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function # More info about Function Resource: https://github.com/awslabs/serverless-application-model/blob/master/versions/2016-10-31.md#awsserverlessfunction
    Properties:
      CodeUri: hello_world/
      Handler: app.lambda_handler
      Layers:
`code`

Comment: Do you have any images and/or larger files as part of your code? Rather upload any type of files/objects not needed directly in your code and store it in S3 or similar. Try accessing it through the AWS SDK rather and see if you can get your Lambda function smaller. In the end the bigger the Lambda function the bigger the cold starts will be as well for your function, so good practice keeping it as lean as you can.

Answer (score 0):

You could check how big the zip-file is before unpacking. If that is larger than 50MB, it will be too big for upload to AWS Lambda. However, you can use a container to package your application, which will increase this limit to 10GB. You can have a look at [`PackageType` in the AWS SAM documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/serverless-application-model/latest/developerguide/sam-resource-function.html#sam-function-packagetype) to change this.

Another solution would be to use lambda layers for any big dependencies that you have.

PS: The flag `--use-container` of `sam build` has nothing to do with the package type of your functions.

Comment: How can I check the size of the zip before unpacking?